# How to resolve Could not load type 'System.ValueTuple`3' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'?

Tags: c#

Getting this error after updating Microsoft.Net.Compilers from `2.1.0` to `3.2.1`. The "Csc" task failed unexpectedly. System.TypeLoadException:

```
Could not load type 'System.ValueTuple`3' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedToolTask.GenerateCommandLineCommands()
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

How to resolve this error? Tried Nuget package update, deleting bin, obj, packages folders, restart VS 2017, but, nothing worked.

Comment: There's no question here. What's your question?

Answer (score -1):

This has hit me a time or two. Which version of Vs are you using?

In the meantime, I'd update all packages thur NuGet(I'm using 2019 here).

- Right click on your project or solution.
- Left click on 'Manage Nuget Packages...'.
- Click on 'Updates' in the upper left hand corner. Then 'Select all packages'
- Then click 'Update' or 'Update All'
- Clean your solution, then rebuild.

If that does not work. Open the 'bin folder, and delete everything in the folder, the clean and rebuild again.

If that doesn't do it, Close all open Visual Studio instants you have open. Navigate to the folder where all your Nuget Packages are store. Delete them all. Re-open your solution. Right click on your solution folder, and left click 'Restore All Packages'. Clean and Rebuild.

Let us know.